# How can i control default Unity grid?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I can show grid in unity by the Show Grid options. However, can i resize grid, or control other grid options?
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "other grid option"?

Comment: I guessed that there would be such a function.., can i resize the grid?

Comment: afaik you can't resize the grid as they represent 1/10/100/... units but you obviously can resize your objects

Comment: I'd just create your own grid with a plane & transparent material